# nestjs how to validates a Bearer token sent via authorization header and returns a boolean

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jwt, nestjs

I've a public route, that need to validate jwt token and return boolean based on the token result, the problem is I can not catch `jwtService.verify(token)`:
Here is my code:

```
async verifyToken(token: string) {
  try {
     const verified = this.jwtService.verifyAsync(token);
  } catch (error: any) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot catch"? also where is `verifyAsync` defined?

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari verifyAsync is imported via dependency injection from jwtService. I mean above try catch block not goes to the catch, even it shows error in console that indicate token is invalid, so in this case I should return false.

Comment: do you need `await this.jwtService.verifyAsync`?

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari No `verifyAsync` is already doing that, another method `verify` is also exists and can use it with async/await. What I want is to find a way to validate token in a public route and then return boolean back as response.

Comment: that's isn't how promises work. If `verifyAsync` is async, its promise could be rejected. And, to catch the rejected promise, you'll need to add the `await`, otherwise that promise will be floating around. Thus `await this.jwtService.verifyAsync` will fix your issue @jones

Comment: @MicaelLevi But faced with a strange issue, that verify always returns invalid token, even I have the correct token.